# Windows 10 Universal App Data Binding not working correctly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-10

I'm new to Windows 10 app development and doing some examples with data binding.

I have two textboxes and I want to write the content in a textblock as soon as a new key is pressed. But the textblock only gets updated as soon as I change the focus of the textbox.

My XAML code:

```
 <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Firstname, Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="{StaticResource ImportantBrush}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Lastname, Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="{Binding IsNameToShort}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Fullname}"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

I'm pretty sure the ViewModel works because as soon as I change to focus everything is fine.

Comment: You have to bind result to textblock in Keyup event of Textbox..

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was thinking on that too but it seemed for me not being the 'right' way. I tried it with the answer of @mikeroneer and this works perfect. However thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged to your binding, then it should work.

Correct XAML Code:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Firstname, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Foreground="{StaticResource ImportantBrush}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Lastname, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Foreground="{Binding IsNameToShort}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Fullname}"/>
```